# How to use netty properly?

Tags: netty

I used netty to write a program in which the server and the client communicate with each other. When the client sends a message to the server, it can be received, but when the server sends a message to the client, it cannot be received.
Can someone give me some Pointers? Thank you very much!

this is server.it can receive message.

```
@Slf4j
public class EchoServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ChannelFuture channelFuture = new ServerBootstrap()
                .group(new NioEventLoopGroup(), new NioEventLoopGroup())
                .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                .childHandler(
                        new ChannelInitializer<NioSocketChannel>() {
                            @Override
                            protected void initChannel(NioSocketChannel channel) throws Exception {
                                channel.pipeline().addLast(new StringDecoder());
                                channel.pipeline().addLast(new StringEncoder());
                                channel.pipeline().addLast(new ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
//                                        log.debug("{}", msg);
                                        System.out.println(msg);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                )
                .bind(8080);

        Channel channel = channelFuture.sync().channel();

        new Thread(() -> {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            while (true) {
                String msg = scanner.nextLine();
                if (msg.equals("q")) {
                    channel.close();
                    break;
                }
                channel.writeAndFlush(msg);
            }
        }, "input").start();


    }
}
```

this is client, not receive message.

```
`@Slf4j
public class EchoClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ChannelFuture channelFuture = new Bootstrap()
                .group(new NioEventLoopGroup())
                .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
                .handler(new ChannelInitializer<NioSocketChannel>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void initChannel(NioSocketChannel channel) throws Exception {
                        channel.pipeline().addLast(new StringEncoder());
                        channel.pipeline().addLast(new StringDecoder());
                        channel.pipeline().addLast(new ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter() {
                            @Override
                            public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
//                                log.info("{}", msg);
                                System.out.println(msg);
//                                super.channelRead(ctx, msg);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                })
                .connect(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 8080));


        Channel channel = channelFuture.sync().channel();


        new Thread(() -> {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            while (true) {
                String msg = scanner.nextLine();
                if (msg.equals("q")) {
                    channel.close();
                    break;
                }
                channel.writeAndFlush(msg);
            }
        }, "input").start();

    }
}
```